# Kernel module cleanup routine runs only when a new module is loaded

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel

I'm currently working on simple hello world type-of kernel modules, following a guide for beginners,
I've created a simple module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Loaded\n");
        return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Unloaded\n");
}
```

I've also created a simple makefile (the module's C source file name is mymodule.c):

```
obj-m += mymodule.o

all:
         make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
         make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

After using make and using `insmod` to insert the module, everything seems fine, dmesg writes "Loaded" as I expected and I move on to use `rmmod` only to find out that "Unloaded" wasn't written into dmesg.
I went on to try some things and found out only when another module is loaded (I copied the same one to a diffrent name, compiled and inserted) the `cleanup_module` functions runs and writes "Unlaoded" as expected, my question is, is it normal? and if so why is it happening? or how do I fix it? in case my assumption was right and `rmmod` should provoke the `cleanup_module` function

Comment: Have you checked the exit status of `rmmod`? If you don't see anything logged it almost surely means that `rmmod` failed to remove the module. You should add the exact commands you are using to the question.

Comment: The exit status of rmmod is 0 - it does work, as I said when I load a new module the cleanup routine runs perfectly, point is, I want it to run without having to load a new module